# Android installation process and Application directory

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I read that during .apk installation process a new user is created and with this new user rights, the Applications directory(.apk is extracted here) in the internal storage is created (in /data/app , not very sure). I can't find any Application directory in /data/app , even /system/app also contain .apk not Application directories . Can someone explain where I can find Application directories ??

Also what are the things happens during installation process (I am interested in knowing if some specific files are copied to specific location).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read wrong :) APKs are not extracted on the file system, just decompressed in memory. So you will only find APK files in `/data/app`, `/system/app`, etc. The whole process is version dependent (for example Jelly Bean adds forward locking/encryption). You need to read the Android source to get the actual details. Start with `PackageManagerService.java`.

Comment: All apps I install goes to /system/app and /data/app is empty. I think only pre-installed app should be there in /system/app. Also can you give me some reference link how apk's are decompressed in memory(fully or partially)

Comment: How do you install the apps and what device are you using? Both resources and code are used, so that would make it 'fully'. See Android source for reference.